# Wordpress get_page() and plugin shortcode not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a query to get a post in wordpress:

```
<?php 
   $page_content = get_page(2);
   echo do_shortcode($page_content->post_content);
?>
```

The page that is being loaded has a shortcode in it that loads a slider. The slider markup is loading but the javascript and css files required for the plugin are not showing up in the source code. How can I fix this?

Comment: a source code or link to the page would be much more helpful than this code . It has nothing to do with the part where you should enqueue scripts..

Answer (score 0):

you did not supply any relative source code or link, but did you load the JS and css ?
Is the slider comes from a plugin ? is it your plugin ? is the plugin activated for said page ? did you `enqueue` your styles and scripts ??

Anyhow, as a first measure , try to load it manually on the page

```
function my_scripts_enq()  
{  
    // Register the script for a plugin:  
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', plugins_url( '/js/custom-script.js', __FILE__ ) );  
    // or  
    // Register the script for a theme:  
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-script.js' );  

    //  then enqueue the script:  
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );  
}  
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_enq' );
```

For fast debug you can can simply try :

```
   if( is_page(42) ){
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_enq' );
}
```

for styles you should do :

```
function load_styles()  
{  
    // Register the style for a plugin:  
    wp_register_style( 'custom-style', plugins_url( '/css/custom-style.css', __FILE__ ), array(), '20120208', 'all' );  
    // or  
    // Register the style for a theme:  
    wp_register_style( 'custom-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom-style.css', array(), 'se16205117', 'all' );  

    // then enqueue the style:  
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-style' );  
}  
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_styles' );
```

BTW - as a side note , From [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page#Examples)

```
$page_id = 2;
$page_data = get_page( $page_id );
```

> // You must pass in a variable to the get_page function. If you pass
>   in a value (e.g. get_page ( 123 ); ), WordPress will generate an
>   error.  By default, this will return an object.

Comment: It does not matter if the id is in a variable or not. The functions accepts an integer value.